# Making "Refreshing a repository after changing line endings" work

Tags: git, github

All links to do this lead to this link: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#platform-all

I am trying to follow this link, but cannot get it to work.

I am on Windows.

I create a bare repository and then clone it to `clone1`.
I add a file to `clone1` with mixed line endings (LF and CRLF) and commit and push.

Now I want to fix line endings.
I set `core.autocrlf` to `true` and create a `.gitattributes` in the repository with `* text=auto`.

Following the steps I delete all except the `.git` directory and then continue with steps:

```
rm .git/index
git reset
git status
```

My git status is telling me I have one file for deletion, this is not what the steps expect - `Show the rewritten, normalized files.`

I then tried to do this without deleting files:

```
rm .git/index
git reset
git status
```

but this results in no changes to be committed.

What I expect is it would normalize the files line endings and the file will have changes to commit.

As many people are pointing to this link to follow, I believe I am doing something wrong but can't see it? Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend a slightly different solution.

Instead of removing the index file and regenerating it, make sure you're using Git version 2.16 or greater. This version adds a new option [`--renormalize`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#git-add---renormalize) for `git add`:

> Apply the "clean" process freshly to all tracked files to forcibly add them again to the index. This is useful after changing `core.autocrlf` configuration or the `text` attribute in order to correct files added with wrong CRLF/LF line endings. This option implies `-u`.

Simply run `git add --renormalize .` and commit.